# TCPDF Adobe does not shows Header and footer

Tags: php, tcpdf, codeigniter-3

Fellows I have an Issue printing Headers and footers using TCPDF.

The classes that prints the pdf are:

```
class MyPdf extends Pdf
{
    private $eventid=null;

    function __construct($event_id,$config=null)
    {
        parent::__construct($config);

        $this->eventid=$event_id;
    }

    function Header()
    {
        if($this->eventid!==null)
        {
            $this->SetFont('dejavusans','',8);
            $this->Cell(0,9,'eventid: '.$this->eventid);
            $this->Ln();
        }
    }

    function Footer()
    {
        $this->setY(-20);

        $x=$this->getX();
        $y=$this->getY();

        $this->Cell(0,9,'Powered By Ecampole.com INC ',0,0,'C');

        $this->setXY($x,$y);

        $this->Cell(0,9,$this->PageNo(),0,0,'R');
        $this->Ln(1);
    }

}
```

And the PDF Library:

```
require_once('/usr/share/php/tcpdf/tcpdf_import.php');

define('FA_PATH',previous_dir(APPPATH).'assets/vendor/awesome/fonts/');

    class Pdf extends TCPDF
    {

      //private $fa=null;

      private $faPath='fontawesomewebfont';

      /**
      *@param $params {Array} Parameters fo the Library.
      *                       It must have the following:
      *                       *)orientation: 'P' for portrait 'L' for landscape by default is 'L'
      *                       *)unit:  'pt' for points please google and look for more options in this parameter
      *                       *)page: The type of page you want eg. A4, A3 etc etc.
      */
      public function __construct($params)
      {

        $orientation= isset($params['orientation'])?$params['orientation']:'P';//By default portrait landscaping
        $unit=isset($params['unit'])?$params['unit']:'pt';
        $page=isset($params['page'])?$params['page']:'A4';
        parent::__construct($orientation,$unit,$page,true, 'UTF-8', false);


        $ci=&get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('path');
        //$fa=(isset($params['fa']) && file_exists($params['fa']))?$params['fa']:FA_PATH.'fontawesome-webfont.ttf';

        //$this->fa=$this->addTTFfont($fa,'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32,FA_PATH);
        //$this->addFont('fontawesomewebfont','',FA_PATH.'fontawesomewebfont');
        //$this->faPath='fontawesomewebfont';
        /*Font setting in order to show UTF-8*/
        //$this->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
        //$this->setFontSubsetting(true);
      }

      /*public function getFontAwesome()
      {
        return $this->fa;
      }*/

      public function getFontAwesome2()
      {
        return $this->faPath;
      }

      public function getHeight()
      {
        return $this->h;
      }

      public function getWidth()
      {
        return $this->w;
      }

      public function bMargin_()
      {
        return $this->bMargin;
      }

      /**
      *We declare it as blank function because by defauld it renders an unwanted black line
      */
      public function Header()
      {

      }

      /**
      *We declare it as blank function because by defauld it renders an unwanted black line
      */
      public function Footer()
        {
        $CI= & get_instance();
        $CI->load->helper('url');

            $this->setY(-15);

            $this->SetFont('dejavusans','',8);
            $x=$this->getX();
            $y=$this->getY();

        $text_size=$this->GetStringWidth('Powered By Example.com INC');
            $this->Cell(0,9,'Powered By Example.com INC',0,0,'C');

        $imagex=$this->getWidth()/2+$text_size/2+1;
        $image=base_url('assets/img/squirrel.png');

        $this->Image($image,$imagex,$y,10,8,'PNG');
        }

      /**
      *Calculate How much height we have
      */
      public function spaceleft_()
      {
        return  $this->getHeight() - $this->GetY() - $this->bMargin_();
      }

      /**
      *It auto breaks the page if remaining space
      *is less that $bias*total_height of the page
      *
      *@param $bias {Float} A floating number betrween 0 and 1.
      *                     0 equals for 0% 1 equals for 100%
      *                     eg. 0.4 equals 40% of the total height
      */
      public function magic_break($bias=0.4)
      {
        $height=$bias*$this->getHeight();
        if($this->spaceleft_()<$height)
        {
          $this->addPage();
        }
      }

      /**
      *Sets The Draw Color Back to Black
      */
      public function resetDrawColor()
      {
        $this->SetDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
      }

      /**
      *Sets The fill Color Back to White
      */
      public function resetFillColor()
      {
        $this->setFillColor(255, 255, 255);
      }

      /**
      *Calculate the image size from pixels to points
      *@param $image {String} The url or the path of the image
      *@param $bias {Int} A scale factor for the image if 0 it does not scale the image.
      *@return {Array} With the $width and $height of the Image
      */
      public function image_size($image,$bias=4)
      {
        list($image_width,$image_height)=getimagesize($image);


        $image_width=$image_width*0.75;
        $image_height=$image_height*0.75;

        if($bias!==0)
        {
          $image_width/=$bias;
          $image_height/=$bias;
        }

        return array($image_width,$image_height);
      }

      /**
      *Converts the image width and image Height to points
      *@param $image_width {Int} The width of the Image in pixels
      *@param $image_height {Int} The height of the image in pixels
      *@param $bias {Int} A scale factor for the image if 0 it does not scale the image.
      *@return {Array} With the $width and $height of the Image
      */
      public function fix_size($image_width,$image_height,$bias=0)
      {
        $image_width=$image_width*0.75;
        $image_height=$image_height*0.75;

        if($bias!==0)
        {
          $image_width/=$bias;
          $image_height/=$bias;
        }

        return array($image_width,$image_height);
      }
    }
```

And the code that Draws the Pdf is:

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    //define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS",APPPATH.'/libraries/font/unifont');

    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    define('TOP_MARGIN',30);
    define('SIDE_MARGIN',5);


    /**
     * Class for Setting The Header and Footer
     */
    class MyPdf extends Pdf
    {
        private $eventid=null;

        function __construct($event_id,$config=null)
        {
            parent::__construct($config);

            $this->eventid=$event_id;
        }

        function Header()
        {
            if($this->eventid!==null)
            {
                $this->SetFont('dejavusans','',8);
                $this->Cell(0,9,'eventid: '.$this->eventid);
                $this->Ln();
            }
        }

        function Footer()
        {
            $this->setY(-20);

            $x=$this->getX();
            $y=$this->getY();

            $this->Cell(0,9,'Powered By Conferience',0,0,'C');

            $this->setXY($x,$y);

            $this->Cell(0,9,$this->PageNo(),0,0,'R');
            $this->Ln(1);
        }

    }


    $pdf new MyPdf($data['header']);

    $pdf->SetAuthor($owner,true);
    $pdf->SetCreator('Example.com INC',true);
    $pdf->SetTitle($title,true);
    $pdf->SetMargins(SIDE_MARGIN,TOP_MARGIN,SIDE_MARGIN);

    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

    /* Add the first Page */
    $pdf->AddPage();

    /*####################### Size Metrics ###########################*/
    $remaining=$pdf->getHeight()-28-18-TOP_MARGIN;
    $available_width=$pdf->getWidth()-SIDE_MARGIN-SIDE_MARGIN;
    //Calculate the hald Width
    $available_width_half=$available_width/2;
    //Bootstap like Grid set the Column Size
    $columns=($available_width)/12;



    ?>
```

But for some reason evincew on linux shows the header and footer while Firefox and Adobe 9.0 Professional on windows do not show them. Also Firefox does not show footer.

Do you have Any idea why does this happen?

Answer (score -1):

`TCPDF` has its own function for handling headers and footers. You can easily use `TCPDF::setHeaderData()` and `TCPDF::setFooterData()`.

Comment: I userd them byt still when print them I do not see the header and footer